# Local Windows Debugger vs Start

Tags: visual-studio-2017

After building my solution in Visual Studio 2017 I noticed that the Start (Run) button is replaced by "Local Windows Debugger". How do I get the Start button back?

NOTE: I have already tried the solution that suggests checking the settings under Tools->Customize, and I've also tried Tool->Export and Import Settings->Reset All

Comment: It just reminds you that you have a choice of debug engines.  Don't panic, the local one is surely the one you like.  So just click it or press F5.

Comment: Thanks Hans. I figured out what the issue was. The file I had open was a .cpp file but when I switched to a .WPF file the Start button appeared as expected. Once again, thanks for your feedback.